# Php merge two elements of an array based on some common value and add other values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a below array:

```
[product] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 1
                [code] => 147818
                [price] => 11
                [name] => Product1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 2
                [code] => 147818
                [price] => 11
                [name] => Product1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 1
                [code] => 567432
                [price] => 31
                [name] => Product2
            )

    )
```

I want to add quantities if the code is same. That is, I want the resulting array to be:

```
[product] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 3
                    [code] => 147818
                    [price] => 11
                    [name] => Product1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [code] => 567432
                    [price] => 31
                    [name] => Product2
                )

        )
```

It should merge the elements only if the code is same. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So what code have you tried to write to achieve this?

Comment: You can achieve this by iterating through the original array, checking if a product with a given code has already been visited - if so, you add quantities of current and previous products with the same code. 

At the end, you should have a new array.

Comment: I would start by asking how you created the first array? If it was from a database query, I would start by changing that

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @RiggsFolly The array was created by form submit and not from database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it merge and sum the `qty` by `code`

```
$products = [
    [
        'qty' => 1,
        'code' => 147818,
        'price' => 11,
        'name' => 'Product1'
    ],

    [
        'qty' => 2,
        'code' => 147818,
        'price' => 11,
        'name' => 'Product1'
    ],

    [
        'qty' => 1,
        'code' => 567432,
        'price' => 31,
        'name' => 'Product2'
    ],
];


$output = [];

for ($i=0; $i<count($products); $i++) {

    if ($output[$products[$i]['code']]['code'] == $products[$i]['code']) {
        $output[$products[$i]['code']]['qty'] += $products[$i]['qty'];
    }else{
        $output[$products[$i]['code']] = $products[$i];
    }
}
$output = array_values($output);

print_r($output);
```